# RegEx expression for Eclipse's search that finds occurrences of a word without another word?

Tags: regex, eclipse, aptana

I need to come up with a RegEx expression that will work with Eclipse's search.

It needs to find every occurance of 'script' that does not have 'jsSrc'.

I've tried these with no luck (using negative lookaheads and lookbehinds)

```
    (?!jsSrc)script(?<!=jsSrc)
```

Would not match this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<% { out.print( jsSrc( request, "/config/pop.config.jsp" ) ); } %>"></script>
```

But would match this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/config/pop.config.jsp"></script>
```

What would be the best expression to use that works in the Eclipse IDE search?

Thanks!

Comment: One difficulty here, besides the general madness of parsing HTML with regex, is that the expression has to account for the text between the `script` and the `jsSrc` before it can scrap the line. So are the lines you are parsing at all consistent or is it "script is here and then at some arbitrary point later maybe a jsSrc"?

Comment: It would be arbitrary and I need to apply it to a few different scenarios. Also, it's not guaranteed that a previous developer didn't use more than one space between attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script(?!.*jsSrc)
```

It will match "<script" if it is not followed by some text that contains "jsSrc".

Alternatively, this will match the whole line:

```
<script(?!.*jsSrc).*$
```

Here is the test data that I used:

```
1: <script src="jsSrc"></script>
2: <script src="something else"></script>
3: <script src="something else jsSrc"></script>
4: <script src="jsSrk"></script>
5: <script src="gsSrc"></script>
```

Only lines 2, 4, and 5 matched using these expressions. Note that I only tested this with single-line expressions, not multi-line ones.